# templated polymorphism via a non-templated base class

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I have the following situation:

```
class Base2
{
};

class Base1
{
    virtual void f()=0;
protected:
    boost::shared_ptr<Base2> base2Ptr;
};


class Derived1 : public Base1
{
    Base1(boost::shared_ptr<Base2> b2)  : base2Ptr(b2) { }

    void f()
    {
        /* Here I would like to know the derived type of base2Ptr */
    }
}

template<typename T>
class Derived2 : public Base2
{
    typedef T result_type;
}
```

Comment: This isn't going to work, because you haven't made declared `operator()` as a `virtual` member in the base class.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Good points. I'll edit the question to make it closer to my real problem (I tried to simplify, but simplified too much).

Comment: Maybe look at Boost.any.

Comment: There is no `base2Ptr` in `Derived1`

Comment: Why is `Derived1` a template? You've written `template<typename T>` but you made no use of the T. Did you mean `template<typename T> class Derived1 : public Base1<T>` where Base1 is a template?

Comment: Actually you can ignore the template on Derived1. It is templated for reasons that are not related to this specific problem.

Comment: Maybe your question should end with code something like this: `int main() { Derived1<....> x ( new Derived2() );`, where you hope that the object will 'know' the dynamic type of the object passed in - i.e. that's it's a Derived2 that's passed into the constructor of `x`, not just a Base2? Is this your goal?

Comment: The words "derived type of base2Ptr" are a bit confusing. Do you mean the "dynamic type of b2"? e.g. `Base * x = new Derived` creates a an object with dynamic type Derived, but the variable x has static type Base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I put some code on [ideone](http://ideone.com/1E6SV) (Edited to have some virtual destructors. This is important so that shared_ptr correctly destructs DoublyDerived2 in the example.))

Based on the comments on the question, I think the ultimate goal is for the constructor of Derived1 to somehow 'know' and 'remember' the *static* type of the object passed into the constructor of Derived1. In particular:

```
Derived2<string> *p = new DoublyDerived2<string>();
// static type of p is Derived2, not DoublyDerived
shared_ptr<Base1> x = something_that_creates_a_Derived1(p);
```

The Derived1 object should know that `p` is of type Derived2, not merely of type Base2

Assuming this is correct understanding of the problem, that code on ideone should solve it. The main trick is that make_Derived1 is a template and the deduced type is used when creating Derived1. Derived1 is itself a template, which ensure that its `foo` method knows the type.

```
template <class T>
shared_ptr<Base1> make_Derived1(shared_ptr<T> ptr) {
    cout << typeid(ptr).name() << endl;
    return shared_ptr<Base1>(new Derived1<T>(ptr));
}
```

and a usage:

```
int main() {
    shared_ptr< Derived2<string> > p ( new DoublyDerived2<string>() ) ;
    shared_ptr<Base1> x = make_Derived1(p);
    x->f(); // prints something like "Derived2", as desired.
}
```

Comment: @IritKatriel, in terms the example I've given, do you need the `foo` to know about the fact that `p` is really a `DoublyDerived2<string>`? Or is it sufficient to know that it is a `Derived2<string>`?

Comment: Yes, this approach should work for me: pass the type as a template parameter along with the shared_ptr, so that the exact type is known. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way for `Derived1<T>::f()` to get a typedef from the `Base2*`.

`Derived2` does have a typedef `result_type` in it, but from the language level, there's no way to guarantee that a separate subclass of `Base2` would also have a typedef named `result_type`. C++ is a statically typed language so you can't write code that relies on a type that might change dynamically based on what sort of subclass is inside `Base2*`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that would be the case. Not all is lost though - I just realized that I can probably extract the type from another static type I have there.